# In C++ algorithm header, why use "!(val < *first)"?

Tags: c++

Here is a piece of C++ code written in the c++ algorithm header file.

```
bool binary_search(vector<int>::iterator first, vector<int>::iterator last, int val)
{
    first = lower_bound(first, last, val);
    return (first != last) && !(val < *first);
}
```

I can understand how this binary_search function work, but I cannot understand why it uses " !(val < *first) " instead of (val == *first).
is there any programming problem with '==' ?

Comment: `!(a<b)` isn't equivalent to `a == b`, it's equivalent to `a >= b`. Further, there is no requirement for types to provide `operator ==`. For a strict weak order pretty much everything is doable with `operator <` (and that's not by mistake).

Comment: @WhozCraig `!(a<b) isn't equivalent to a == b` not by itself, but it is equivalent given precondition of `a <= b`. Which is indirectly enforced by `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm has simply been specified to only require the type to be comparable with `<`, and no other comparison operator such as `==`.

This allows the algorithm to be used with types that do not implement `==` (as rare as that may be). That would not be the case if the algorithm used `==`.

Note that the algorithm already uses `<` within `lower_bound` (through the default comparator), so that requirement would not be relaxed by the use of `==`.

Comment: It also mirrors the overload that takes a `Compare`, which might be entirely unrelated to `==`